# How to Post to LinkedIn using R?

Tags: r, api, post, share, linkedin-api

I am trying to post (share) to LinkedIn using R and the REST api.  I followed the code example here: https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-linkedin.r

It does a GET call which is working for me, but I haven't managed to get the POST to work right.  The error I receive is:

```
         Date: 2015-09-17 10:00
         Status: 403
         Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
         Size: 144 B
         {
           "errorCode": 0,
           "message": "Access to posting shares denied",
           "requestId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
           "status": 403,
           "timestamp": 1442509229748
```

Below is the code I am trying to use:

```
    POST("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json",        
         body = list(
                content = list(title="Title",
                description ="Description"),
                comment = "Comment",
         visibility = list(code="anyone")
         ),
         config=list(token = token)
         )

     #submitted-url=url,
     #submitted-image-url=imageurl
```

The documentation is here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

I have w_share enabled in the application, so I am not sure what the problem is.  Do I need the "submitted-url" and "submitted-image-url"?

I'd appreciate a working POST code example.

Thanks.